# how can we add comma separated hyperlink in datatable jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, split, datatable

This is my view where i want to split the comma separated values of a column AlertType
with individual comma value to popup

[image: This is my view where i want to split the comma separated values of a column AlertType with individual comma value to popup]

```
                        table = $('#DataQualityDT').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            destroy: false,
            "serverSide": true,
            retrieve: true,
            "searching": false,
            sColumns: true,
            bFilter: true,
            fixedHeader: true,
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',

            "sAjaxSource": "/hello/xyz",
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "CustomerAlertID", "value": Customerid });

            },
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {
                    "mData": 'RowNum',
                    "aTargets": [0],
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "bSearchable": false
                },
                {
                    "mData": 'PositionDate',
                    "bSearchable": true,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "aTargets": [1]
                },
                {
                    "mData": 'AlertID',
                    "bSearchable": true,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "aTargets": [2],
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="#" id=' + row.AlertID + ' data-userId=' + row.AlertID + ' class="hreflink_search"> ' + data + ' </a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "mData": 'Alert_Type',
                    "bSearchable": true,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "aTargets": [3],
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                      
                            return '<a  href="#" id=' + row.Alert_Type + ' data-userId=' + row.Alert_Type + ' class="link"> ' + data + ' </a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "mData": '',
                    "aTargets": [4],
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "bSearchable": false,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a href='# AlertID=" + row.AlertID + "' data-userId=" + row.AlertID + "' class='hreflink_create' ><i style='cursor:pointer'></i> Create</a>  ";
                    }
                }
            ],
            "drawCallback": function (settings) {
                $('#loading').hide();
            },
            "order": [[1, 'asc']]
        });
```

How can I split this Alert_Type value(IR , MC, MM_MMP, MM_Remit, Telepin, WCB) to invidula comma hyperlink in  so that i can call individual popup for individual alerttype.
I'm lost in how to approach this. thank u in advance

Comment: Please provide your View code

Comment: @SteliosPantelopoulos i have jut updated my question can u check once

Comment: Create a for loop where you iterate the data. For each data element you append to a string '<a  href="#" id=' + row.Alert_Type + ' data-userId=' + row.Alert_Type + ' class="link"> ' + data[i] + ' </a>'